# Understanding Complete Metric Spaces and Cauchy Sequences

Tags: general-topology, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

From my own definition, I have concluded that a complete metric space is a set and a metric where the set consists of no holes in it.  Book definitions describe that "A complete metric space is a metric space in which every Cauchy sequence is convergent." I understand that a metric is a distance measuring device defined on an arbitrary set, and when speaking of a "metric space" they are talking about a set and a metric defined on that set (X,d).  However, I have yet to get an understanding of a "Cauchy sequence" when speaking of a Complete Metric Space.  I am seeking an example of a complete metric space, relatively one that I can interpret.

Comment: @Michael how would I go about proving that in an example.  If I were to explain to someone else, how could I use what you commented to back if up?

Comment: I was puzzled by your first sentence so ignored it in my answer.  But what do you mean by "From my own definition, I have concluded that a complete metric space is a set and a metric where the set consists of no holes in it."  What is your definition of a complete metric space??

Comment: Sorry, I just deleted it because it also came up in the answer. A proof that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete would go something like this: Show that a Cauchy sequence is bounded. By the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has a convergent subsequence. Finally, show that a Cauchy sequence with a convergent subsequence is convergent and combine these facts.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker can you repost what you deleted?

Comment: @user58315 Sure: If $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $d$ is given by $d(x,y)=|x-y|$, then $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example -1: Any set endowed with the discrete metric is complete: every Cauchy sequence is eventually constant, hence convergent.

Example 0: A subset $Y$ of a complete metric space $(X,d)$ is complete with the inherited metric if and only if it is closed.

Example 1: The real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ with $d(x,y) = |x-y|$.  (Some people regard using $\mathbb{R}$ as an early example of a metric space to be circular; I am not one of them.)

Example 2: Any compact metric space.  (More generally, one has the characterization of compact metric spaces as those which are complete and [totally bounded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded).)

Example 3: a) For any positive integer $n$, if $(X_1,d_1),...,(X_n,d_n)$ are complete metric spaces, and we endow the Cartesian product $X = \prod_{i=1}^n X_i$ with any of several reasonable metrics -- e.g. $d(x,y) = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} d(x_i,y_i)$ -- then $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space.
b) If $\{(X_n,d_n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of complete metric spaces, and we endow $X = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i$ with the metric $d(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i} \frac{ d_i(x_i,y_i)}{1+d_i(x_i,y_i)}$, then $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space.

Example 4: For any metric space $X$, let $C_b(X)$ be the set of bounded, continuous functions $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, endowed with the metric $d(f,g) = \sup_{x \in X} |f(x) - g(x)|$.  This is a complete metric space and indeed a [Banach space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space).

Example 5: The completion of any metric space.  For instance, completing the rational numbers with respect to the $p$-adic metric one gets the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of [p-adic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number).

---

I thought about taking seriously the idea of formalizing "no holes" as a definition of a complete metric space.  Here is what I came up with:

**Proposition**: For a metric space $(X,d)$, the following are equivalent:
(i) For any isometric embedding $\iota: (X,d) \rightarrow (Y,d)$ of $X$ into another metric space $Y$ and any sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$, if $\iota(x_n)$ converges in $Y$ then 
$x_n$ converges in $X$.
(ii) $X$ is complete.

Proof: The basic observations here are that if $\iota: (X,d) \rightarrow (Y,d)$ is an isometric embedding and $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $X$, then:
$\bullet$ $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy iff $\{\iota(x_n)\}$ is Cauchy, hence also
$\bullet$ if $\{ \iota(x_n)\}$ is convergent, then $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy.
Then (ii) $\implies$ (i) is immediate; to show (i) $\implies$ (ii) look at the completion $\iota: X \rightarrow \tilde{X}$ of $X$.

Thus the "holes" in $X$ are detected by embeddings into larger spaces.  I am skeptical though that this definition would be helpful for beginning students: aside from relying on the existence of the completion of a metric space, the idea of considering all possible embeddings of one metric space into another seems relatively abstract and sophisticated.

Comment: Interesting numbering.

Comment: @Michael: it's hard to defend, but it seemed reasonable at the time.

Comment: Is it because the first example is underground, and never heard of it?

Comment: I really like your characterization of completeness.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks, I liked it too.  Here's a question: using this alternate definition can one show that every metric space isometrically embeds in a complete metric space without rehashing the standard theory of Cauchy sequences and equivalence classes thereof?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark There is the following quick proof that a metric space can be completed: You embed $(X,d)$ isometrically in the Banach space of bounded real functions on $X$ with supremum norm. Just pick some fixed $x^*\in X$ and take $x\mapsto f_x$ given by $f_x(y)=d(x,y)-d(y,x^*)$. So you complete the space by embedding it and taking the closure.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for this construction; I had not seen it before.  (It's slightly reminiscent of a standard construction of the Stone-Cech compactification.) What I was asking though is a way to show that every metric space embeds into a space which has "no holes" in the sense given above.  Does your construction work for this too?

Comment: @Pete Well, the space of bunded functions on $X$ has certanly no holes. Te quetion is whethr one can verify this using your definition without Cauchy sequences. My feeling is that this unikely. Your criterion basically asks wether a space is closed under every embedding, which means all added points must have positve distance from the original space in the ambient space. The only way to test internally whether such points could exist that I can imagine is by employing something like Cauchy sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Saying that it has no holes in it may not be a very accurate description. As an example, for any open set in $\mathbb{R}$ there exists a metric (possibly different from the usual metric) that generates the usual topology, and is complete. Even for a set as $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, which seemingly has a whole within it. However, note (!) that this set is not a complete metric space with the usual metric. Let me explain why so in a moment.

So, how could one define this notion of completeness more precisely?

- If $(X,d)$ is a metric space, we say that a sequence $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}\subseteq X$ is a Cauchy sequence, if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $d(x_{n},x_{m})<\varepsilon$ for all $n,m\geq n_{\varepsilon}$. So in other words, if for any fixed positive constant there exists an index from which onwards the members of the sequence are closer than this fixed constant from each other.
- We say that a metric space $(X,d)$ is complete if every Cauchy sequence $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}\subseteq X$ converges to some $x\in X$.

In the case of the usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ defined on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, one may note that $(\frac{1}{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence that does not converge to any point in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Hence this metric space is not complete.

A common example of a complete metric space is $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with the usual metric, or any closed subset of theirs.

Answer (score 2):

The essential point in the definition of  Cauchy sequences is the following: You can test whether a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq0}$ is Cauchy just by looking at the $x_n$ themselves; you don't have to know their limit, which maybe doesn't even exist.

Now a Cauchy sequence is a sequence that hopefully converges, because ultimately the terms of the sequence are very near to each other. A metric space where all Cauchy sequences indeed *do* converge is called *complete*.

The metric space ${\mathbb R}$ is complete. This is is a *deep* theorem about the fine structure of ${\mathbb R}$. Other theorems about limits, like
$$a_n\to a,\quad b_n\to b\quad \Rightarrow\quad  a_n+b_n\to a+b$$
are simple consequences of the definitions and of the continuity of the arithmetic operations.

So the question arises whether  incomplete metric spaces can arise in a natural way. Consider the open interval $I:=\ ]0,1[\ \subset{\mathbb R}$. It inherits the metric from ${\mathbb R}$ and is a metric space in its own right. The sequence
$$x_n:={1\over n}\in I\qquad(n\geq1)$$
converges to $0\in{\mathbb R}$; therefore it is a Cauchy sequence. On the other hand it cannot converge to some other point $\xi\in {\mathbb R}$, so in any case it is divergent in $I$. This shows that $I$ is not complete, even though nobody has placed any holes there.

Answer (score 1):

Before moving on, you have probably seen the concept of a Cauchy sequence in the Euclidean spaces $\mathbb{R}$:

> A sequence $\langle x_n \rangle_{n=1}^\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is a *Cauchy sequence* if for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\| x_m - x_n \| < \epsilon$ for all $m,n \geq N$.  (Where $\| \cdot \|$ is the Euclidean norm on the underlying space; for $n = 1$ this is just the absolute value.)

Moving from the Euclidean spaces to general metric spaces just involves replacing the "$| \cdot - \cdot |$" in the definition above with "$d ( \cdot , \cdot )$", where $d$ is the metric under consideration.

So what is a Cauchy sequence?  At an intuitive level it means that the points of the sequence eventually "cluster together" (*i.e.,* become arbitrarily close to each other).  To check that such a sequence converges we need to somehow find some point about which all of the sequence elements eventually cluster.  Perhaps in this sense we can say that there are no "holes": any sequence that eventually clusters is in fact eventually clustering about a point of the space.

But before you become too attached to this idea, consider the following degenerate example (also essentially given in other answers).

> Consider the set $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers with the metric inhereted a subset of $\mathbb{R}$: $d ( m , n ) = | m - n |$.  It is not hard to show that it is complete: the only Cauchy sequences are the eventually constant sequences, which trivially converge.  (If $\langle x_n \rangle_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Z}$, consider the least $N$ such that $d ( x_m , x_n ) < 1$ for all $m,n \geq N$).

However I doubt people look at the above space and say that there are no holes; I think most would actually say that it is *mostly* holes!